# Seeking something like 'world' basemap of QGIS in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm a new ArcGIS Pro user and am looking for a basemap very similar to the basemap that comes up in QGIS when you type 'world' in the coordinate box.

It is a blank map of the countries with borders marked and requires no attribution.

Is there such a thing in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=702026e41f6641fb85da88efe79dc166#overview)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided ArcGIS Pro is capable of reading geopackages, whats's wrong with using the referred

`C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.7\apps\qgis-ltr\resources\data\world_map.gpkg`

... (or whatever your installation path is) directly? This wouldn't give you "such a thing" but exactly *the same thing*.

Comment: Good answer if the OP has both ArcGIS and QGIS installed on the same device.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much!